# Weird serialization error when entity is serializable

Tags: c#, serializable

I get the following error when trying to serialize an object:

```
Type
'TEST.Common.TestObj`1+<>c__DisplayClass1`1[[TEST.Common.TestEntity,
TEST.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' in Assembly
'Test.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
 is not marked as serializable.
```

I have the `[Serializable]` attribute both on the `TestObj` entity, all it's base entities and all entities related to their properties. What else can cause this "is not marked as serializable" error?

And what does `` c__DisplayClass1`1 `` even means??

Comment: How about posting your real code instead of making us guess your classes and codes? A similar [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629134/cant-reach-children-element-of-a-groupbox-after-serialize-it-wpf) Try to read and understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googled your c_DisplayClass1'1 and found the following:

http://rantdriven.com/post/2011/07/09/The-Mysterious-2b3c3ec__DisplayClass1.aspx

It has some links and explanations about how it might be an event handler you're trying to serialize.

This seems to be an helpful comment:

> The main issue has to do with what's being serialized. By default,
>   event handlers are internally represented by a compile-time generated
>   field. This field holds a reference to the delegate(s) to be invoked
>   when the event is raised.
>
> Using your example above, the exception is caused because you're using
>   an anonymous method that accesses resources beyond its defined scope.
>   Under the covers, a class (probably called "<>c__DisplayClass1") is
>   created to represent the anonymous method. This method doesn't get
>   marked with the [Serializable()] attribute. When you attempt to
>   serialize your object it attempts to serialize its fields and the
>   exception is thrown.
>
> You can fix your code in one of several ways:
>
> If you want to maintain serialization on the event (which is on by
>   default for a Serializable class), the easiest thing to do is to move
>   your 'addedMessage' variable into the anonymous method so that it
>   doesn't access any local variables in the containing scope.
>
> If serialization of the event isn't important to you, you can declare
>   your event field manually, marking it with the [NonSerialized()]
>   attribute and then use the add and remove accessors on the event block
>   to manage delegate references.

Comment: Yeah, 9 times out of 10 this turns out to be an event handler

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize a compiler generated closure class which is not marked as serializable. There is no way to have those annotated with the `Serializable` attribute.

Comment: This usually means it is a captured variable context class due to an event handler